# Why is Alamofire POST-Api-call not working?

Tags: swift, post, alamofire

The POST-parameters are not passed. Why?

Is there another possibility to make POST-API-Calls?

```
let parameters: [String: String] = ["username" : "test", "password" : "test"]

        Alamofire.request("http://192.168.2.117/evk-ph/api/verify_user.api.php",
                          method: .post,
                          parameters: parameters,
                          encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                          headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
                             switch response.result {
                             case .success:
                               print(response)
                             case .failure(let error):
                               print(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the error output?

Comment: Create a breakpoint and print out response into console or if error is being printed copy it here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that maybe work for use just do a simple changes in your code

```
func postJSON() {

    let param = ["username":tFusername.text!,"password":tFpassword.text!] as NSDictionary //GET TEXTFIELD VALUE

    let url = "YOUR URL HERE"


    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: (param as! Parameters), encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result{
        case .success(let json):
            print(json)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(param)
                //HANDLE YOUR CODE HERE 
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

Use this Function in your viewDidLoad() or as you required.

Comment: Response closures are called on the main queue by default in Alamofire, so there's no need to dispatch to main.